# read shape files in R

Tags: r, sqldf

Hi i have the following code that reads the shape file

```
states.shp<-readShapeSpatial("elpo12p010g.shp")
#trying to subset just one state from the loaded file
az_election_results<-sqldf("select * from states.shp where STATE_NAME='AZ'")
```

When i run the code it says the states.shp table doesnt exist. I see the states.shp is there as value data type in R, I could see that in the values window, but not sure why this error is coming. I very new to R programming. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `.` in the object name.

This should work:

```
az_election_results <- sqldf("select * from 'states.shp' where STATE_NAME='AZ'")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to quoting, we can also place it inside square brackets (similar to all those column names that have spaces in `sql server`)

```
sqldf("select * from [states.shp] where STATE_NAME='AZ'")
```